# How to get the equation of the boundary line in Linear Discriminant Analysis with sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I classified some data being split in 2 categories, with LinearDiscriminantAnalysis classifier from sklearn, and it works well, so I did this:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis as LDA

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.25) # 25% of the dataset are not used for the training
clf = LDA()
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Then I manage to make prediction with it and that is fine here.

But, all that is in an ipython notebook, and I'd like to use the classifier elsewhere. I've seen the possibility of using pickles and joblib, but as I only have 2 groups and 2 features, so I though that I could *just* get the equation of the boundary line, and then check whether a given point is above or below the line to tell which group it belongs.

From what I understood, this line is orthogonal to the projection line and goes through the mean of the clusters' mean. I think I got the clusters' mean with `np.mean(clf.means_, axis=0)`.

But here I'm stuck on how to use all the attributes like `clf.coef_`, `clf.intercept_`, etc... to find the equation of the projection line.

*So, my question is how can I get the boundary line equation given my classifier.*

It is also possible that I did not understood LDA properly, and I'd be delighted to have more explanations.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decision boundary is simply line given with

```
np.dot(clf.coef_, x) - clf.intercept_ = 0
```

(up to the sign of intercept, which depending on the implementation may be flipped) as this is where the sign of the decision function flips.

Comment: this is a generic equation for every single linear classifier. They only differ in the way they find coef and intercept. LDA assumes that data come from normal distributions with the same covariances and finds a closed form solution for the optimal separation line

Comment: I got a `ValueError: shapes (1,2) and (127,2) not aligned when doing the dot product. Also I only have 2 features, so maybe it explain the dim issue above, because doing clf.coef_*x - est.intercept works. Then it gives me the points on the projection line, right ? if yes, I find the slope and intercept of it with a regression, and get the orthogonal line to this one going through the mean of the clusters, but when I draw it, it seems ok but there are a few points on the wrong side of the line, and it looks like the slope isn't exactly right. What am I doing wrong ? Thanks

Comment: You have to transpose your X,  thats all. You do not have to regress anything, this is the exact, canonical equation. C0*x + C1*y - intercept =0. There is nothing left to do, just plot this line. Some points will end on the wrong side.  lda does not guarantee 100% training accuracy

Comment: You seem to be confused with the means idea. Forget about the means. You do not need them to do anything.  They are used to calculate coefs and intercept nothing Else. At this point they are discarded

Comment: hum, I think I'm confused with everything! To what `x` in `np.dot(clf.coef_, x)` refers to?

Comment: X in the answer is your whole space. You are not supposed to put your data there. This is mathematical equation for whole Space in a canonical form. Just use any library to plot a line given in canonical form

Comment: plotting `f(x) = -clf.coef_[0][0]/clf.coef_[0][1] * x - clf.intercept_/clf.coef_[0][1]` looks like the right line, but I derived it from `C0*x + C1*y + intercept = 0`, is that right ?

Comment: Yes, but only if coef01 is not zero. This is why canonical form Ax+By+C=0 is better then high school equation y=ax+b

Comment: ok but you wrote `C0*x + C1*y - intercept =0` not  `C0*x + C1*y + intercept =0`. So I was unsure about what you meant. But thanks you very much anyway, this is what I wanted. Maybe you can edit your answer so it reflects what I wanted.

Comment: Also, do you have a reference (like a document for a class) for that ? Because I couldn't find any.